# Meaning of "L'agricoltura è l'economia del paese"

Tags: meaning

I have read the following sentence in an Italian language learning tool:

> L'agricoltura è l'economia del paese (= Agriculture is the economy of the country)

Is the Italian sentence meaningful? The English translation does not make much sense. I guess that the Italian sentence can be a way of saying "Agriculture is the main economic activity of the country" ?

Comment: Both the Italian sentence and its translation mean exactly the same thing. Whether you consider it meaningless or not is your judgement call :).

Answer (score 4):

You are right, the intended meaning of the sentence is that agriculture is the main economic activity of the country. In English it could be translated as

> Agriculture is the backbone of the country.

If your question regards the use of the expression, I would personally not use it, unless maybe when contradicting somebody who thought that agriculture were not important for a given country, stressing an accent on "è". The reason I would not use it is because it sounds irretrievably vague. Maybe some more widely accepted expressions could be

> L'agricoltura è fondamentale per il paese.
>
> L'agricoltura è il settore chiave del paese.